# How to resolve dependency issues with erlang rebar?

Tags: erlang, rebar

I'm trying to add swagger to an existing demo project [erlang_rest_api](https://github.com/donowar/erlang_rest_api) as a learning experience, but I don't seem to be getting very far...

I cloned the repos:

```
git clone https://github.com/dronowar/erlang_rest_api
```

Then I added cowboy_swagger to `rebar.config`:

```
{cowboy_swagger, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/inaka/cowboy_swagger.git"}}
```

And when I build I get:

```
Dependency not available: jsx-2.9.0 (undefined)
Dependency not available: cowboy-2.5.0 (undefined)
Dependency not available: ranch-1.6.2 (undefined)
Dependency not available: trails-2.1.0 (undefined)
```

So I add to `rebar.config`:

```
{jsx, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/talentdeficit/jsx.git", {tag, "2.9.0"}}},
{ranch, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/ninenines/ranch.git", {tag, "1.6.2"}}},
{trails, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/inaka/cowboy-trails.git", {tag, "2.1.0"}}},
```

And then I **delete** the `deps` directory and build again:

```
...
==> poolboy (get-deps)
==> sync (get-deps)
==> katana_test (get-deps)
==> jsx (get-deps)
ERROR: Failed to load erlang_rest_api/deps/trails/rebar.config: {error,
                                                                                      {34,
                                                                                       file,
                                                                                       {error,
                                                                                        function_clause,
                                                                                        [{erl_eval,
                                                                                          '-inside-an-interpreted-fun-',
                                                                                          [katana_test],
                                                                                          []},
                                                                                         {erl_eval,
                                                                                          eval_fun,
                                                                                          6,
                                                                                          [{file,
                                                                                            "erl_eval.erl"},
                                                                                           {line,
                                                                                            829}]},
                                                                                         {erl_eval,
                                                                                          expr_list,
                                                                                          6,
                                                                                          [{file,
                                                                                            "erl_eval.erl"},
                                                                                           {line,
                                                                                            888}]},
                                                                                         {erl_eval,
                                                                                          expr,
                                                                                          5,
                                                                                          [{file,
                                                                                            "erl_eval.erl"},
                                                                                           {line,
                                                                                            240}]},
                                                                                         {erl_eval,
                                                                                          expr_list,
                                                                                          6,
                                                                                          [{file,
                                                                                            "erl_eval.erl"},
                                                                                           {line,
                                                                                            888}]},
                                                                                         {erl_eval,
                                                                                          expr,
                                                                                          5,
                                                                                          [{file,
                                                                                            "erl_eval.erl"},
                                                                                           {line,
                                                                                            240}]},
                                                                                         {erl_eval,
                                                                                          eval_lc1,
                                                                                          6,
                                                                                          [{file,
                                                                                            "erl_eval.erl"},
                                                                                           {line,
                                                                                            706}]},
                                                                                         {erl_eval,
                                                                                          eval_generate,
                                                                                          7,
                                                                                          [{file,
                                                                                            "erl_eval.erl"},
                                                                                           {line,
                                                                                            735}]}]}}}
make: *** [Makefile:7: deps] Error 1
```

`katana_test` seems to be some kind of testing tool.  I tried adding that repos (inaka/katana-est) to `rebar.config` but it's not working, either.

I also tried tagging cowboy as version "2.5.0" as listed in "undefined" earlier, but that made no difference.

**Do we really need to this specific, listing every dependent repository of every dependency?**

I also tried using hex instead:

```
    {jsx, ".*"},
    {ranch, ".*"},
    {trails, ".*"},
    {cowboy_swagger, "2.1.0"}
```

but I still got:

```
Dependency not available: jsx-.* (undefined)
Dependency not available: trails-.* (undefined)
Dependency not available: cowboy_swagger-2.1.0 (undefined)
ERROR: compile failed while processing
```

**Am I missing another dependency?**

Comment: Please, update in body of question link from `[1]: https://github.com/donowar/erlang_rest_api` to `[1]: https://github.com/dronowar/erlang_rest_api`. You skip `r` in `donowar`, correct is will be `dronowar`

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises from the fact that `cowboy_swagger` is built to be used with [rebar3](http://rebar3.org/) and it's not compatible with the old rebar, but erlang_rest_api is using the old rebar, as you can see in its [`Makefile`](https://github.com/dronowar/erlang_rest_api/blob/3133599fd7648f876b9582383753f145df609653/Makefile#L2).

The solution to your problem may be as simple as using rebar3 to build the project. But careful if you do that since that would break `make run` and `make run-local`. You'll have to figure out how to achieve the same results using releases.